# How to Remove Save and New from one2many form view in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

how to hide save and new button from one2many form view in odoo 10?[image]

Comment: any body please answer

Comment: Just add another button it will replace this buttons, and you can even hide that button which you added. Very simple

Comment: This btn is inbuilt function write on js file. If you want see this code than follow go to addons -> web -> static -> src -> js -> view -> open form_comman.js and follow line 889.

Comment: bro we know where is actual code, thats not matter how to hide this form view only

Comment: You can use css for this or else for this particular view hide using JS.

Answer (score 2):

This is a nasty hack but worked for me.

In an inherited view, add the following:

```
<xpath expr="//form" position="inside">
    <style>
        .btn-primary:nth-child(2){
            display:none !important;
        }
    </style>
</xpath>
```

Or something similar depending on the HTML structure of your page

Comment: this will hide all such positions generally. will be a conflict

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide save and new one button, you mean that you don't want the user to  add or edit the records.

```xml
   <field name="your_one2many_field">
         <tree  edit="false" create="false">
             ...
             ....
             ....
```

and if you want to hide delete also just make your field readonly.

```xml
   <field name="your_one2many_field" readonly="true"/>
```

so what do you want exactly what option you want the user to still have.

Answer (score 0):

Make One2many field readonly="1" in XML